# Strange behaviour when redirecting from action with Remix

Tags: node.js, typescript, remix.run

I am experimenting with Remix, trying to build a very simple application. I have two routes - an `auth.tsx` and `_index.tsx` inside my `routes` folder.

`auth.tsx`

```js
export default function Auth() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const nameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const surnameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const emailRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const termsAndConditionsRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetcher.data?.errors?.email) {
      emailRef.current?.focus();
    } else if (fetcher.data?.errors?.password) {
      passwordRef.current?.focus();
    } else if (fetcher.data?.errors?.termsAndConditions) {
      termsAndConditionsRef?.current?.focus();
    }
    if (fetcher.state === "idle" && fetcher.data?.success) {
      setSuccess(true)
    }
  }, [fetcher])

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      ....
    </>
  )
```

Here is a section of the `action` function that handles the login

```js
if (_action === "login") {
    const userLogin = await verifyLogin(email as string, password as string);

    if (!userLogin) {
      return json(
        { success: false, errors: { email: "Invalid user credentials", password: null, termsAndConditions: null } },
        { status: 400 }
      )
    }

    return await createUserSession({
      request,
      userId: userLogin.id,
      redirectTo
    })
  }
```

And here is the `createUserSession()` function

```js
export async function createUserSession({
  request,
  userId,
}: {
  request: Request;
  userId: string;
}) {
  const session = await getSession(request);
  session.set(USER_SESSION_KEY, userId);
  throw redirect("/", {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": await sessionStorage.commitSession(session, {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 7 days
      }),
    },
  });
}
```

The problem is that on successful login, the user is being redirected to the index route, but the default function never gets called.

`_index.tsx`

```js
export default function Index() {
  const user = useOptionalUser()
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

How do I make sure Remix renders the index route again upon redirect so I can pick up the user data and pass it for example to the header?

Comment: How are you submitting to the action via fetcher? Redirects should be followed even from `fetcher.submit()`